# JavaScript Automatic Type Conversion Confusion

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Given this script:

```
var number = NaN;

if (!number) {
  alert("yes");
}

alert(number == false);
```

Why does the first expression `` `!number `` evaluates to true, while the second expression `number == false` evaluates to false?

http://jsfiddle.net/8EWG4/

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with NaN being 'falsey'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a look in this article:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/30/10-oddities-and-secrets-about-javascript/

There's some tricks about javascript, including informations about NaN:

**NaN is a Number**

You thought null being an object was ridiculous? Try dealing with the idea of NaN — “not a number” — being a number! Moreover, NaN is not considered equal to itself! Does your head hurt yet?

```
alert(typeof NaN); //alerts 'Number'
alert(NaN === NaN); //evaluates false
```

In fact NaN is not equal to anything. The only way to confirm that something is NaN is via the function isNaN().

Comment: You can actually use that property as a way of checking for `NaN` - if `x !== x` yields `true`, then `x` must be `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) says so:

`x == y` is defined as (11.9.3):

> If x is **NaN**, return **false**.

And `!` calls `ToBoolean` (9.2) first (and then returns the opposite):

> The result is **false** if the argument is +0, −0, or **NaN**; otherwise the result is true

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate a variable is NaN ( not a number ), consider using `isNaN(number)` . It will give you correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

From wikipedia - [JavaScript syntax, boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Boolean):

> When used in a logical context, 0, -0, null, NaN, undefined, and the empty string ("") evaluate as false due to automatic type coercion.

```
!NaN == true
```

So, as NaN is coerced to `false`, `!NaN` evaluates to `true`.

However, `NaN` is not equal to `false` - it is a different type/value.

Comment: Then why does `alert("" == false);` evaluate to true?

Comment: @Oliver Weiler: That's also in the specification. `==` should call `ToNumber` on both arguments in case of a string and a boolean, and `ToNumber` returns `0` for both `""` and `false`.